# Getting mkdir: cannot create directory ‘wagmi’: Permission denied

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm currently using WSL2 and trying to make a directory in /home/ directory but I'm getting Error " mkdir: cannot create directory ‘wagmi’: Permission denied ". I think it needs permission but how? how can I give permission to make it happen?

Answer (score 3):

Use sudo before command, Like

```
sudo mkdir name_of_folder
```

Then enter a password for your system, Do not worry if you see the password while typing, this is one of the security methods in Linux. After you type the word, press the Enter button